# How to serialize a Dictionary<string, List<string>> using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: .net, dictionary, datacontractserializer

When I try to have this class serialized I get a CommunicationException.
Do I need to use any specific CollectionDataContract markup to get this working?

```
[DataContract()]
public class MyClass
{
  [DataMember()]
  public Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should just work (see examples below). What's the full exception which you get?

```
public class StackOverflow_6966835
{
    [DataContract()]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        MyClass GetMyClass();
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public MyClass GetMyClass()
        {
            return new MyClass
            {
                dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
                {
                    { "one", "uno un eins".Split().ToList() },
                    { "two", "dos deux zwei".Split().ToList() },
                    { "three", "tres trois drei".Split().ToList() }
                }
            };
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stand-alone serialization");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        MyClass c = new Service().GetMyClass();
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, c);
        Console.WriteLine("Serialized: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now using in a service");

        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetMyClass());

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is something like "There was an error reading the pipe: unrecognized exception 109 (0x6d)" (translated into English). By the way, I'm using NetNamedPipeBinding.

Comment: It's possible that the server closed the channel for some reason. Try enabling tracing at both the client and the server, the traces should contain the reason for that.

Comment: I found the problem. As you said, it should work fine and there was indeed nothing wrong my code example in itself. However that example was obviously simplified and the problem was in the real code. (I was accidently trying to send an inherited type over the wire that was not marked [DataContract] or KnownType). Thanks for your reassurance that it should have worked!